# How Do Ordinary Developers Try Out isPermissionRevokedByPolicy()?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

API Level 23 added [`isPermissionRevokedByPolicy()` on `PackageManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#isPermissionRevokedByPolicy%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). It is supposed to return `false` if a requested permission is blocked for a certain package "by policy":

> Typically the device owner or the profile owner may apply such a policy.

Is there anything that a developer can do to cause `isPermissionRevokedByPolicy()` to return `false` for some package/permission combination, short of going through the whole Android for Work set of shenanigans?

Comment: Did you find anything about that? I guess the only way to test could to be use the Test DPC app. It's open source, but still a lot of work just to test one method. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testdpc

Comment: @fasteque: No, I don't have any answers, which is why the bounty is still outstanding. I kinda lumped Test DPC into the "whole Android for Work set of shenanigans". Test DPC is decidedly under-documented, I have no idea how to map stuff from that "Manage app permissions" page to actual Android permissions that might be covered by `isPermissionRevokedByPolicy()`, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course, I might be wrong, but it looks like the short answer is "no, there's not", unfortunately.

A bit more extended answer:
Here's the code of ApplicationPackageManager:

```
@Override
public boolean isPermissionRevokedByPolicy(String permName, String pkgName) {
    try {
        return mPM.isPermissionRevokedByPolicy(permName, pkgName, mContext.getUserId());
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Package manager has died", e);
    }
}
```

where mPM -

```
private final IPackageManager mPM;
```

It's being initialized in the constructor, which is called by ContextImpl.getPackageManager():

```
@Override
public PackageManager getPackageManager() {
    if (mPackageManager != null) {
        return mPackageManager;
    }

    IPackageManager pm = ActivityThread.getPackageManager();
    if (pm != null) {
        // Doesn't matter if we make more than one instance.
        return (mPackageManager = new ApplicationPackageManager(this, pm));
    }

    return null;
}
```

([source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/d59921149bb5948ffbcb9a9e832e9ac1538e05a0/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java))

Going deeper and looking into ActivityThread.getPackageManager():

```
public static IPackageManager getPackageManager() {
    if (sPackageManager != null) {
        //Slog.v("PackageManager", "returning cur default = " + sPackageManager);
        return sPackageManager;
    }
    IBinder b = ServiceManager.getService("package");
    //Slog.v("PackageManager", "default service binder = " + b);
    sPackageManager = IPackageManager.Stub.asInterface(b);
    //Slog.v("PackageManager", "default service = " + sPackageManager);
    return sPackageManager;
}
```

([source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/d89b76a58dcffa7dbc5974d14c7914f44233bef3/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java))

All these steps I was doing to find the actual implementation of *isPermissionRevokedByPolicy* btw. Then I had to find who extends IPackageManager.Stub - it's PackageManagerService ([source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java)).

So here is the actual implementation:

```
@Override
public boolean isPermissionRevokedByPolicy(String permission, String packageName, int userId) {
    if (UserHandle.getCallingUserId() != userId) {
        mContext.enforceCallingPermission(
                android.Manifest.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL,
                "isPermissionRevokedByPolicy for user " + userId);
    }
    if (checkPermission(permission, packageName, userId)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return false;
    }
    final long identity = Binder.clearCallingIdentity();
    try {
        final int flags = getPermissionFlags(permission, packageName, userId);
        return (flags & PackageManager.FLAG_PERMISSION_POLICY_FIXED) != 0;
    } finally {
        Binder.restoreCallingIdentity(identity);
    }
}
```

Potentially to "fake" the status of particular permission, you'd need to hack checkPermission and getPermissionFlags methods. The problem, I'm afraid, that there's no obvious way how to feed ApplicationPackageManager with overriden PackageManagerService, at least, without reflection.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not necessarily trying to fake the revocation. I just want to get this method to return `true` with the least effort. For example: does [`setCameraDisabled()` on `DevicePolicyManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setCameraDisabled%28android.content.ComponentName,%20boolean%29) cause `isPermissionRevokedByPolicy()` for `Manifest.permission.CAMERA` to return `true`? `setCameraDisabled()` can be invoked by a regular device administrator, not necessarily a device owner, policy owner, or other Android for Work things.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yep, I might be little inaccurate in writing focusing particularly on revocation in the text, but nevertheless, it's true for all sort of faking. About setCameraDisabled() - i'll think more about it. If anything comes into my mind - I'll update the answer..

Comment: @CommonsWare setCameraDiabled() does not cause isPermissionRevokedByPolicy() to return true.This is really confusing why there are multiple apis to control device features. As per my understanding managed provisioning is same as device administration with few extra things. may be google might think of eliminating redundant api going forward. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @7383: "setCameraDiabled() does not cause isPermissionRevokedByPolicy() to return true" -- well, now, that's disappointing.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a direct way. But as a work around if runtime [permissionstate](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PermissionsState.java) of the calling package can be changed, then ispermissionrevokedbypolicy() will return false. But i feel that would also be a tricky part.